# way to model a one-to-one relationship in schema?

Tags: json, backand

For example I have a table of `cars`, each has a `model` and a `make`. A car can only have one of each, and there is a table of `models` and `makes`, with their ids auto-generated. Can I reference these in my `cars` table? What would the JSON look like?

I tried to create a new field in the `cars` table and specify `id` in the "Via" text box, but it just creates a new column in the corresponding table, **id1**. Is there a proper way?

Here is my sample schema JSON:

```
  {
    "name": "cars",
    "fields": {
      "model": {
        "object": "models"
      },
      "make": {
        "object": "makes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "models",
    "fields": {
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "make": {
        "object": "makes"
      },
      "id": {
        "collection": "cars",
        "via": "model"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "makes",
    "fields": {
      "models": {
        "collection": "models",
        "via": "make"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "id": {
        "collection": "cars",
        "via": "make"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Back& there is no one-to-one relationship by definition but we you have looking for is one-to-many and you almost got it, see the below Model that works.
In the below model a car can have single model and single make (of course a makes and models can have many cars - this is the many part):

```
{
  "name": "cars",
  "fields": {
    "model": {
      "object": "models"
    },
    "make": {
      "object": "makes"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "models",
  "fields": {
    "cars": {
      "collection": "cars",
      "via": "model"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "make": {
      "object": "makes"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "makes",
  "fields": {
    "cars": {
      "collection": "cars",
      "via": "make"
    },
    "models": {
      "collection": "models",
      "via": "make"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```